# how to access firebase database before creating a custom token for privileged claims?

Tags: node.js, firebase, jwt, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to create a custom token with privileged claims according to the information stored for user in database

```
admin.auth().getUserByEmail(req.body.email)
  .then(function(userRecord) {
    var uid = userRecord.uid;

     firebaseClient.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(req.body.email,req.body.password).then(value => {  
      return theToken(uid,res);  
          }).catch(err => {
            console.log(' .......... '+ err);
            return passwordWrong(uid,res);
          });
    return ;  
  }).catch(function(error) {
    return passwordWrong(uid,res);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    return emaiWrong(res);
  })
})

theToken = function(uid,res){
  console.log(".................................password correct");
  var path = "user/"+uid;
  admin.database().ref(path).once('value', (snapshot) => {
    var printthis = snapshot.val();
  console.log("..............",printthis);
  });

  return admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid)
    .then(function(customToken) {
            return res.status(200).json({ 
                  message: customToken.toString()
                });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error creating custom token:", error);
    });   
}

passwordWrong= function(uid,res){
  console.log(".................................................."+"passwordWrong");
  return res.status(200).json({ 
    message: 'password invalid'
  });
}

emaiWrong = function(res){
  return res.status(200).json({
    message: 'email invalid'
  })
}
```

The problem is I am not able to access the database: The below code is ouputting: .............. null

```
var path = "user/"+uid;
  admin.database().ref(path).once('value', (snapshot) => {
    var printthis = snapshot.val();
  console.log("..............",printthis);
  });
```

How to access the database before creating the token? My database looks like:
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: The screenshot you shared shows Cloud Firestore, but the code is trying to access the Realtime Databases. While both databases are part of Firebase, they're completely separate and don't share an API. If you want to access data from Cloud Firestore, use the API documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I am getting TypeError: admin.database.collection is not a function. I also tried with database() with no luck!

Comment: There is no method `admin.database.collection`. You might be looking for `admin.firestore().collection`? Please study the documentation carefully, and possibly follow one of the codelabs, as it will save you waiting for answers from us.

Comment: could you please refer me to a good code labs. thanks

Comment: Firestore codelab for web/javascript: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firestore-web/